# Installing sun-java6-jdk with apt-get on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apt-get, sun-java6-jdk

I have followed the instructions on numerous pages, such as [this](http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/sun-java6-jdk-has-no-installation-candidate-on-ubuntu-10-04/), which say to run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

However, when I do this I *still* get the following error:

```
me@mycomputer:~$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jdk has no installation candidate
```

I realize Java is available from many other sources, but for reasons that I can't get into here I *must* use this specific version.

What can I do to get this installed?

Comment: you can install it manually using this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6

Answer (score 7):

The Sun/Oracle JDK package is no longer available in Ubuntu due to Oracle retiring the 'Operating System Distributor License for Java'.  Story [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/java-to-be-removed-from-ubuntu-uninstalled-from-user-machines/).

Originally Canonical were going to make it so that existing installations of Sun's JRE/JDK would get *removed* on an apt-get update, but they [reversed that decision](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/canonical-reverse-java-uninstall-decision/) (however updates/installs will no longer be available).

The recommendation is for users to transition to the OpenJDK 6 package.  You can still install the Oracle JDK by downloading from Oracle's website, but it has to be done manually.

Comment: Does OpenJDK exist for 10.04?

Comment: @dfrankow Seems like it according to the [package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/openjdk-6-jdk), though don't know how up-to-date it is.

Comment: Turns out openjdk-6-jdk was available, but did not do what I wanted.  It was too early in its dev cycle.  I ended up using Sun's jdk from http://superuser.com/a/439915/56544.

Answer (score 5):

Also, you might find [this blog post](http://blog.flexion.org/2012/01/16/install-sun-java-6-jre-jdk-from-deb-packages/) helpful. It worked for me and was totally painless (script install vs building your own Java package):

> You can find the script and full usage [instructions on github](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6).
>
> The quick and dirty guide for using this script is as follows:
>
> ```
> cd ~/
> wget https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/raw/master/oab-java.sh -O oab-java6.sh
> chmod +x oab-java6.sh
> sudo ./oab-java6.sh
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The following command should help you get sun jdk6 in ubuntu 10.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I couldn't get this to work on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: This worked for me on 10.04, which was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are really good instructions for building your own sun-java packages here:

https://github.com/rraptorr/sun-java6

The packages work great for me in Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 x64/i386.

Answer (score 0):

Install OpenJDK instead

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`

Answer (score -3):

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

worked fine for me on ubuntu 10.04

thanks.

Comment: QA wants Sun Java not OpenJava.